# Parrot OS screen flickering

Tags: linux, nvidia, parrotsec

I have installed Parrot OS on my Asus ROG laptop with Windows 10 (dual boot).
When I am using the Parrot OS, sometimes
the screen just starts flickering until I move the mouse. 
GUI apps not working well the GUI is flickering too.

Hardware I have on my laptop:

- CPU: i7 7th gen
- GPU: GTX 1050ti
- RAM: 8 GB

I have tried to install the Nvidia drivers,
but after the installation is complete I reboot the laptop but the Parrot OS is stuck in boot up process. 
So I uninstalled the drivers from recovery mode and then rebooted –
and all works the same.